# Date comparison between two objects

Tags: c++, calendar, comparison

I had to write a program for my laboratory at college. In the program I want to compare two dates in the format day/month/year. I know how to do that,but without including the hour.For now I'm converting the date into days passed since year 0000 and simply compare these two values. The problem is my teacher told me to add hours and now I dont know how to compare this. Any suggestions?  Present code bellow

.h File

`class timee`

```
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
int hour;
long int count;

public:
    timee();
    timee(int,int,int,int);
    long int daysCount();
    bool operator>(const timee &);
    bool operator>=(const timee &);
    bool operator<=(const timee &);
    bool operator==(const timee &);
    timee & operator=(const timee &);
    timee & operator+=(int);
    timee & operator-=(int);
    long int operator-(timee &);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const timee &);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &, timee &);
};
```

Here the .cpp file

```
timee::timee():day(0),month(0),year(0),hour(0),count(0){}

timee::timee(int day,int month,int year,int hour):day(day),month(month),year(year),hour(hour)
{
    count = daysCount();
}

/*calculating the number of days that have passed since year 0000*/
long int timee::daysCount()
{
        int month_days[] = {0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334};

        // calculate number of leap years.
        int leapyears = year / 4;
        if (isLeapYear(year) && month < 3)
        {
            // If this is a leap year
            // And we have not passed Feburary then it does
            // not count.....
            leapyears   --;
        }

        // convert year/month/day into a day count
        count = year * 365 + month_days[month-1] + day + leapyears;

        return count;
}


/*convering the date from days since year 0000 to year/month/day format */
timee timee::dateConversion()
{
    int month_days[] = {0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365};

    //calculate number of leap year
    int leapyears = year / 4;
    if (isLeapYear(year) && month < 3)
        {
            // If this is a leap year
            // And we have not passed Feburary then it does
            // not count.....
            leapyears   --;
        }

    //calculating year

    year = (count-leapyears)/365;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {

            if((count-leapyears)%365 > month_days[i])
                        {
                            month = i+1;
                        }

        }

    day = ((count-leapyears)%365)-month_days[month-1];

    return *this;
}

bool timee::operator>(const timee &obj) 
{
    return count>obj.count;
}

bool timee::operator>=(const timee &obj) 
{
    //if((count>=obj.count) && (hour>=obj.hour)) return true;
    //else if((count<=obj.count) && (hour>obj.hour))return false;
}

bool timee::operator<=(const timee &obj) 
{
    return count<=obj.count;
}

bool timee::operator==(const timee &obj)
{
    return count==obj.count;
}

timee & timee::operator=(const timee &obj)
{
    day=obj.day;
    month=obj.month;
    year=obj.year;
    hour=obj.hour;
    count=obj.count;
    return *this;
}

timee & timee::operator+=(int value)
{

    count+=value;
    this->dateConversion();
    return *this;
}

timee & timee::operator-=(int value)
{
    count-=value;
    this->dateConversion();
    return *this;
}

long int timee::operator-(timee &obj)
{
    return count - obj.count;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const timee &obj)
{
    os << "Date: " << obj.day << "." << obj.month << "." << obj.year << " Hour: " << obj.hour << " " << obj.count << endl;
    return os;
}

istream & operator>>(istream &is, timee &obj)
{
    cout << "Type day, month and year" << endl;
    is >> obj.day >> obj.month >> obj.year >> obj.hour;
    obj.daysCount();
    return is;
}
```

There is one of my attempts to overload the >= operator. Please help.

Comment: hours would add fractional days, so you can't still return a `long int` if you want to keep with a similar algorithm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196153/find-how-many-seconds-past-since-1-1-1970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` in your algorithm refers to the number of days passed since year 0.

Though, the smallest precision you should have now is not a day, but an *hour*. So you should simply create a variable `totalHours` being the number of *hours* passed since year 0.

```
//Calculate number of days since year 0
count = year * 365 + month_days[month-1] + day + leapyears;
//Convert to number of HOURS since year 0, and add additional hour
totalHours = count*24 + hour;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was helpful, but now I got some other problem. I want to make a function which works inversely which means to get day/month/year and hour from the "hour passed since year 0". For now I'm trying to get the year , but somehow it does not work exactly as it should for example converting the date 1/1/2016 hour 1 into "hour..." and then back gives me the year 2017. Is it because of using int values?
`year = ((count-leapyears)/24)/365;`

Comment: If I got it right, what you want to do now is from a single component (number of hours since year 0), get the number of years, months, days and left hours?
This is quite more complicated than what you have done so far

Comment: The main purpose why I use this format is that it is much simpler to add/shift the date by x days( at least I think so). But as you said, converting it back is quite tough.

Comment: Well, shifting the date by x days when having the number of years, months, days and hours is simpler than getting the number of years, months, days and hours from sole total hours in my opinion.
Example: shifting from 1 day, you would try to increment `day`, and if that is higher than the maximum number of days in your month, you also increment `month`, then  if that exceeds 12, you increment `year`

Comment: It was my first thoght, but my programe is something like an event scheduler. There are 3 views of events availabe. Daily, weekly and monthly. In each case I want to create an object which I'm gonna compare with. I want to make it possible to skip within days/months/weeks by pressing `+` or `- `. Example: in the daily view by pressing `+` the date of the object which I'm comparing with is increasing by one(`day`). And when I was designing this functions(working as you said) which will manage all this shifting , it became only a huge cascade of if statements.

Comment: This operation being a cascade of if statements is quite normal when working with such date formats. For cleaner code, you could create several functions incrementDay(), incrementMonth(), incrementYear(), ...
so incrementDay() would check for its own maximum day bound, and call incrementMonth() if it is exceeded, then incrementMonth() would do the same, ...

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible relations between `count` and `obj.count` inside `operator >=`. Either `count < obj.count` or `count == obj.count` or `count > obj.count`. The same holds for `hours` and `obj.hours`. That gives 3 * 3 = 9 possible combinations. Write down what the result of the operator should be for each combination and then find the easiest way to express that in your code.

Note that you don't need to do this for each comparison operator. Typically you implement `operator <` and then define the others in terms of that one.